# How to load jquery plugin only if the Google Maps API is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, lazy-loading, coffeescript

To facilitate the work with the Google Maps API, I am developing a jquery plugin. It have some defaults. follows:

**Defaults jquery plugin  (Code in coffee-script)**

```
(($, window, document) ->

    # Defaults
    defaults =
        zoom: 16
        disableDefaultUI: true
        zoomControl: true
        zoomControlOptions:
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE 
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        mapTypeControl: true
        mapTypeControlOptions: 
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

...
```

Notice the options `zoomControlOptions`.

My problem is that the JS file is unique for every page, the script:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

is on the contact page (which is where I use the API).

This plugin depends on the google maps API to work, how to load the plugin only on the contact page? Better yet, **how to load the plugin only if the Google Maps API is available**?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your wrapper, write this:

```
return if not google?.maps?
```